# Cant Add Columns in Existing Site Content Type

Tags: 2013, 2010, content-type

I am trying to do very simple task in SharePoint site collection.  I created a site column and assigned it to a group. Now i want to add newly created site column into existing site content type.

When i go to Site Settings--> Site Content Types--> "Name of Content Type". I no longer have link to add new column in content type. This is what i see:

[image]

Then i went to sharepoint designer to do the same task, Now it gives me error saying:

[image]

This has never happened to me, I did some research that content types can be set to read only, if that is the case, how we undo read only?

Answer (score 0):

It might be inherited from the content type hub. If that is the case you have follow below steps.

1. Go to the Content Type Hub site.
2. Go to site settings.
3. Go to the site content types and open the one you want to add a column.
4. Add column and re publish.
5. After few minutes it will be added.

Comment: When i do that it says all items that are using that content types are set to readonly and change cant be applied.

Comment: First thing this content type inherited from the content type hub, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Advanced Settings and set the read-only flag to No. But be aware, this detaches your content type from the hub. The whole purpose of the CT hub is to centrally manage content types, and you're bypassing that.

[image]